# Java API to read SAP Crystal Report file and Extract all the queries

Tags: java, java-8, crystal-reports-2008

Need to extract all sql queries used in SAP Crystal RPT file using java api.

I have used eclipse report pluglin to view the sql but it list down the table and column used and not SQL Query

Comment: Please explain: What is the output you are expecting, and what is the output you got. Also: How does your code look like?